# CCD cam to USB - AV grabber for linux

Tags: linux, usb, hardware

I was wondering if there is an AV Grabber that supports Linux. I have IC-348 model I.C.U (international camera unit) camera made in P.R.C, which uses a Sony CCD 420TVL. I want to grab the video output and use it in a program that I am writing. The thing is that I couldn't find a good CCD Cam to USB hardware that supports Linux. Is there one? Can you please give me a model name? Or can you tell me another way to get CCD Cam image in to a Linux laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thorlabs is one of the rare manufacturer supporting Linux for CCD Cam. You'll find their driver [here](http://www.thorlabs.de/software_pages/ViewSoftwarePage.cfm?Code=DCx) and a good CCD one [here](http://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=2916). Beware that's supported only for 32-bits distribution.

If you don't want a Thorlabs one, you'll find here [a list](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/molyned/web-cameras.htm) of CCD cam.

This list indicates if cam is supported under Linux or not.